# How can use Template String in EJS

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am using EJS for the first time in my nodejs app and i need to use some template string inside EJS but i keep getting an error
Below is a code snippet i was working on

```
<% const msg = `Hi i am interested in your product ${window.location.href}` %>
```

In the above code i need to attach the current url to the string the assign it to the variable **msg**
please help on how i can achieve this.

I have also tried using <%- %> delimiters.  but it is still not working

Comment: Why you are using `window.locatlion.href` on the server side (node.js)? Server side... you are supposed to know it already from the request itself. Your code seems to be a browser related javascript and not Node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EJS renders the template on the server-side, so you don't have `window` object there.

Instead, you could get the URL from the server and pass it to the template.

For example with Express:

```
let url = req.protocol + "://" + req.get("host") + req.originalUrl;
res.render("index", { url });
```

Comment: Hi was trying to do this but failed ` <% const msg = `Hi i am interested in your product ${req.protocol + "://" + req.get("host") + req.originalUrl;} ` %> `

Comment: The text his i am interested ... is a string literal and is enclosed in with back ticks

Comment: To do that you have to pass the `req` object when you are rendering the template (as seen above with the url), and use something like this: <% const msg = `Hi i am interested in your product ${req.protocol + "://" + req.get("host") + req.originalUrl}` %>